# In your opinion, what's an acceptable level of frame rate drops for a React Native application?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native and was interested in hearing how others perceive frame rate drops.  When using [Scrollable Tab View](https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view) and LayoutAnimation, I see frame rates intermittently drop from 60fps to 50-55 fps on an iPhone 5s.  Performance on a slow Android device running 4.1.1 can be as low as 48 fps.  What is an acceptable level of droppage?

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using Scrollable Tab View and I share same concern - I tested it on Android, JS fps drops to 20-30 for a moment while UI fps drops to 50 or so, again, just for a moment. I wouldn't notice the drop if I wasn't using the performance monitor, so I believe that this frame rate is somewhat OK.